# Split row with yearly value into rows with monthly values

Tags: r

I have a table with a yearly aggregate value. I want to split them up into the monthly values by dividing "Total" number by 12.

```
library(readr)
myData = read_delim("Date,b,c,d,Total\n2018,NA,NA,NA,12\n2018,0.5,0.5,NA,24\n2018,0.3,NA,0.5,36\n", delim=",")
myData 
# A tibble: 3 x 5
   Date     b     c     d Total
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1  2018  NA    NA    NA      12
2  2018   0.5   0.5  NA      24
3  2018   0.3  NA     0.5    36
```

desired output (for the first row, I'm expecting 36 rows in total):

```
   Date       b     c     d     Total
 1 2018-01-01 NA    NA    NA        1
 2 2018-02-01 NA    NA    NA        1
 3 2018-03-01 NA    NA    NA        1
 4 2018-04-01 NA    NA    NA        1
 5 2018-05-01 NA    NA    NA        1
 6 2018-06-01 NA    NA    NA        1
 7 2018-07-01 NA    NA    NA        1
 8 2018-08-01 NA    NA    NA        1
 9 2018-09-01 NA    NA    NA        1
10 2018-10-01 NA    NA    NA        1
11 2018-11-01 NA    NA    NA        1
12 2018-12-01 NA    NA    NA        1
```

I already checked the accepted answer here: [Break summed row into individual rows in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348104/break-summed-row-into-individual-rows-in-r)
but unfortunatley this is not working for me.

Comment: `myData <- myData[rep(1:nrow(myData), each = 12),]; 
myData$Total <- myData$Total/12`

Comment: thanks, renamed dataframe

Comment: Also: include the packages you are using. `read_delim` is not from base R, but from `readr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually need monthly dates, you can use `complete` to do that.

I created a unique ID for each year based on the `Total` (you may have to play with that depending on how your data is actually organized).  I then made your date column into a date based on the first of the year.  Then I used `complete` to fill out the rest of the months of the year.  `fill` was used to complete the rows, and `mutate` to divide the total by 12.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
library(lubridate)

myData = read_delim("Date,b,c,d,Total\n2018,NA,NA,NA,12\n2018,0.5,0.5,NA,24\n2018,0.3,NA,0.5,36\n", delim=",")
myData 
#  # A tibble: 3 x 5
#     Date      b      c      d Total
#    <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
#  1  2018 NA     NA     NA        12
#  2  2018  0.500  0.500 NA        24
#  3  2018  0.300 NA      0.500    36

myData %>%
  mutate(group_id = group_indices(., Total)) %>% 
  mutate(Date = dmy(paste("01/01/",Date))) %>% 
  group_by(group_id) %>% 
  complete(Date = seq.Date(Date[1],by = "month",length.out = 12)) %>% 
  fill(b,c,d,Total) %>% 
  mutate(Total = Total/12) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-group_id)

#  # A tibble: 36 x 5
#     Date           b     c     d Total
#     <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#   1 2018-01-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#   2 2018-02-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#   3 2018-03-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#   4 2018-04-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#   5 2018-05-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#   6 2018-06-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#   7 2018-07-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#   8 2018-08-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#   9 2018-09-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#  10 2018-10-01    NA    NA    NA  1.00
#  # ... with 26 more rows
```